# Cоздание папки

Tags: pascal

В переменную `x` я буду вводить название папки.
Далее программа в определённом месте, например, в папке 3 (`C:\папка1\папка2\папка3`) должна создать папку с введённым мною названием.
Мне, например, не ясно, как "связать" переменную с функцией `MkDir` и где прописывать путь `C:\папка1\папка2\папка3`?

Что в этом коде дописать и/или изменить?

```
var x : string;  
begin  
Writeln('название папки?'); Readln(x);  
MkDir()  
end.
```

Comment: @Иван777, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var x,y : string;
begin  
y := 'c:\папка1\папка2\папка3';
Writeln('название папки?'); Readln(x);  
MkDir(y+'\'+x)
end.
```

Comment: @Иван777, награждать единственным баллом было не обязательно, достаточно было просто нажать кнопку над цифрой возле ответа.

Comment: он еще 2 мне отдал :)

Comment: Я был рад до неприличия поэтому отдал всё что имел. Награждать балами это плохо, или плохо то что мало? "нажать кнопку над цифрой возле ответа" - нажал конечно, только чтобы это нажатие имело вес, нужно минимум 15 очков уважения, а не мои какие то жалкие 3. А вообще конечно огромное спасибо за ответ, ибо на других ресурсах отвечали то, что я итак через гугул найти могу.

Comment: @Иван777, просто для меня и @Shrek 1-2 балла - это как слону дробинка, а вам бы они еще пригодились:)

Answer (score 3):

Еще правилом хорошего тона чтобы программа не вылетала делать проверку.

```
begin
  {$I-} // отключаем системную проверку
  Writeln('название папки?'); 
  Readln(x);
  MkDir(x); // в текущей директории создаст.
  if IOResult <> 0 then
    WriteLn('Не могу создать папку.')
  else
    WriteLn('Папка создана!');
  {$I+}

end.
```

вообще в паскале нужно постоянно делать такую проверку, отключать системную и дописывать свою, а иначе программа постоянно будет вылетать с критической ошибкой. Знаю по своему опыту 4ре года на нем программировал. В том месте где папку нельзя создать, можно вернуть пользователя при помощи **goto** на место ввода названия папки. в общем проверять все и всегда, когда используешь системные штуки.

ps у [[@insolor](/users/1365/insolor)](/users/1365/insolor) по поводу того как связать папку и переменную.